# How do I update the dates (by 30 days) in the files going to that specific location in unix?

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, scripting

How do I update the dates (by 30 days) in the files going to that specific location in unix? Can awk or sed help ?

File format is as below -

Thomson: xyz
Format: 1
Character_set: ASCII8
File_type: event_file
File_subtype: mobile_call
File_group_number: 1
File_in_group_number: 1
Total_files_in_group: 19
Source_ID: source
Tag: tag -v13

This file produced by GTFplaintext 0.1:

```
Event: "61765","1","2014/01/03-13-00-00.00",,"GBP",,,,,,,,,,"61765","0345351816","1407",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Footer: text_data_transfer_file
AuditValue_1: 1
AuditValue_2: 0
End: text_data_transfer_file
Lines: 15
Characters: 351
Checksum:
Security_checksum:
End_of_file:
```

In the above file I need to go to the line starting with 'Event:' and update the date
 "2014/01/03-13-00-00.00" by 30 days (only date needs to be updated, while time can remain same).
There are 20k such files in a directory, for which the dates have to be updated.

Comment: Note that some date and time combinations are invalid: `TZ=America/Sao_Paulo date -d '2012-10-21T00:00'`

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` and the `Date::Manip` module, you could do:

```
 perl -MDate::Manip -pi -e 's|^Event.*?"\K\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d|
   UnixDate(DateCalc("$&", "30 days later"), "%Y/%m/%d")|e' file1 file2...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  /^Event:/{
    d=substr($0,match($0,"[0-9]{4}(/[0-9]{2}){2}"),RLENGTH)
    "date +\"%Y/%m/%d\" -d \""d" 30 days\""|getline ds
    sub(d,ds)
    }
  1' file
```

For lines which starts from `Event:` find `substr`ing `match`ing date format and put in in variable `d`. Then use system `date` command to set variable `ds` as date more than `d` for `30  days` and `sub`stitute `d` by `ds` in string.

Comment: but the problem is there are mutiple lines starting with Event and each line has different date, if let's assume the below event has date as 2014/01/03, other Event (next line) may have date as 2014/01/08 and next event may have different date. All such Events in the file need to be moved ahead by 30 days -Event: "61765","1","2014/01/03-13-00-00.00",,"GBP",,,,,,,,,,"61765","0345351816","1407",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @Unix_Novice And what is the question? Something do not work?